# What subpanel or breaker box and power wire do I need for my gym/shed?

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel, subpanel

I have a16x24 shed/ home gym. I have already installed the Romex in the walls for the outlets. They will be on 2 breakers.  I also will have a breaker for interior and exterior lights.  I also will need a 240 outlet for a heater now, and the ability to add a 240 outlet for a sauna later.  I want to do as much as I can myself but will obviously get a electrician to make the connection to the house and wire the new subpanel/ breaker box.

What type of sub-panel should I install and what type of wire should I run from the meter at the house to the shed? How do I ground it and will the power company need to change anything?

Comment: Also take the [tour] so you know how to use this site. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.

Comment: How many watts are the heater and the sauna?

Answer (score 2):

Starting with the minimums:

- 3 single breakers (2 receptacles, 1 lights) = 3 spaces
- 2 double breakers (heater, sauna) = 4 spaces
- main breaker *or* backfed double breaker = 2 spaces (you need something for a disconnect, and this is easier/cheaper than a separate disconnect switch)

Which means your absolute minimum is 9 spaces (as a subpanel) or 7 spaces (as a "main" panel). Practically speaking, that means at least a 12 space panel. In reality, often a much larger panel is cheaper, believe it or not, because a larger panel will often include some "free" breakers. For example, in a quick search I found a [GE 100A 20 space panel with extra breakers included](https://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-100-Amp-20-Space-20-Circuit-Main-Breaker-Indoor-Load-Center-Contractor-Kit-TM2010CCUBK1/304736527) for less than $100 at Home Depot:

[image: GE Panel]

That includes 3 20A single breakers and 1 30A double breaker. So you don't have to add much to it to get started, but you have *lots* of room for expansion.

With a panel like that, your feed can be anything *up to* 100A. But it doesn't have to be 100A. Typical feeds are 60A and 90A. 60A because often (especially historically) that was the largest inexpensive feed breaker. 90A because it is the maximum capacity for aluminum 2 AWG wire, and that happens to often be a very good deal because it is used a lot and commodity priced. Your minimum depends technically on a load calculation, but arguable would be the load of the heater + the load of the sauna + some extra for lights and receptacles. 60A would likely be enough, 90A definitely enough.

As far as the heater, depending on your climate you may want to consider a mini-split heat pump, which will provide air conditioning as well and generally cost a lot less for heating than resistance heat. But the up-front cost will be higher than simple resistance heaters.

Next: conduit vs. cable for the feed. You can use individual wires in conduit or use a cable. A cable is in theory less work and expense, except that a cable has to be buried deeper than conduit, though it does vary depending on the type of conduit. Conduit, if large enough, also allows for future expansion if needed.

And finally: GFCI. Almost everything will need to be GFCI-protected. For 120V circuits, the least expensive way to do this is to use GFCI/receptacles. For 240V circuits (heater, sauna), you will need to use GFCI/breakers. The sauna will definitely require GFCI (because "water"). A hardwired heater (or heat pump) may or may not require GFCI, depending on NEC version and any local rules. A plug-in heater (or heat pump or other 240V appliance) generally needs GFCI as of NEC 2020, but local rules vary.